# Replace nth consecutive occurrence of a value

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I want to replace the nth consecutive occurrence of a particular code in my data frame. This should be a relatively easy task but I can't think of a solution.

Given a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(Values = c(1,4,5,6,3,3,2),
                 Code = c(1,1,2,2,2,1,1))
```

I want a result

```
df_result <- data.frame(Values = c(1,4,5,6,3,3,2),
                        Code = c(1,0,2,2,2,1,0))
```

The data frame is time-ordered so I need to keep the same order after replacing the values. I guess that `nth()` or `duplicate()` functions could be useful here but I'm not sure how to use them. What I'm missing is a function that would count the number of consecutive occurrences of a given value. Once I have it, I could then use it to replace the nth occurrence. 
[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/how-do-i-remove-all-but-one-specific-duplicate-record-in-an-r-data-frame?rq=1) had some ideas that I explored but still didn't solve my problem.

**EDIT:**

After an answer by @Gregor I wrote the following function which solves the problem

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

replace_nth <- function(x, nth, code) {
  y <- data.table(x)
  y <- y[, code_rleid := rleid(y$Code)]
  y <- y[, seq := seq_along(Code), by = code_rleid]
  y <- y[seq == nth & Code == code, Code := 0]
  drop.cols <- c("code_rleid", "seq")
  y %>% select(-one_of(drop.cols)) %>% data.frame() %>% return()
}
```

To get the solution, simply run `replace_nth(df, 2, 1)`

Comment: Please explain your desired output in more detail.

Comment: So which nth value do you wish to replace? Is it the 2nd and the7th? Or the 2nd after a 1?

Comment: Some times you mention consecutive occurrences, sometimes you don't. You don't give a sample `n` in your question... this could be a lot clearer. Does the `Values` column matter at all?

Comment: In this example I want to replace every 2nd consecutive occurrence of 1 (in Code column).

Comment: And see `data.table::rleid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, code_rleid := rleid(df$Code)]
df[, seq := seq_along(Code), by = code_rleid]
df[seq == 2 & Code == 1, Code := 0]
df
#    Values Code code_rleid seq
# 1:      1    1          1   1
# 2:      4    0          1   2
# 3:      5    2          2   1
# 4:      6    2          2   2
# 5:      3    2          2   3
# 6:      3    1          3   1
# 7:      2    0          3   2
```

You could combine some of these (and drop the extra columns after). I'll leave it clear and let you make modifications as you like.

Comment: Perfect. `rleid()` was what I needed. I incorporated your code into my function - see the edited question. Thanks